# Columns vs records

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm a newbie to SQL and am designing a database tool that, in part, cross-references data specific to localities in Australia.  A locality is defined as a unique town+postcode combination.  There are approximately 15,000 localities, and about 200 data types related to each locality (e.g. median income, population).

The 15,000 localities rarely change.  The 200 data types change frequently.

In a way it seems odd to have a table with 15,000 columns and only 200 rows, but this seems like the best configuration.

Does it matter which gets used as the column and which gets used as the row?

Comment: Hi, I think you have to think a bit about normalization of your database, here is a [documentation of microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description) and here a [description from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#:~:text=Database%20normalization%20is%20the%20process,part%20of%20his%20relational%20model.)

Comment: I don't think any current relational database supports a table with 15000 columns, so that's not an option to begin with (let alone the wrong design)

Comment: Simplest distinction between rows and columns - rows present similar items, columns present single item attributes. For you [similar] items are localities and therefore they became rows, "data types" are attributes of locality and they will be columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate design for your data would probably make the locality a *single* column.  Each separate locality would then have its own separate record.  As for the 200 data types, let them be 200 separate columns.  So use this design:

```
locality | median income | population
Syndey   | 76340         | 1002307
...
```

If any of the 200 points of metadata for any locality need to change, then you may simply do an update to change it.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  That is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You would store the locality/postcode as *columns* and probably the data types too:

```
postcode   town    median_income    population
```

Even 200 rows for the metrics might be a lot for a table.  Databases usually limit the number of columns, with some as few as 250 or so.  So, you might consider splitting the values into separate tables, based on themes.

A more important consideration is how to handle changes in the values *over time*.  Assuming that all are updated at the same time, you can add an additional key, say "year":

```
year    postcode   town    median_income    population
```

You are probably interested in the most recent year, so you can add an index to the table for the most recent year.  Also, you might want to partition the table by year for performance reasons (assuming your database supports partitioning).

If the individual metrics are updated on their own schedule, then you might want to update in place but keep an audit table to keep track of the historical data.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  I hadn't considered the time aspect, but you're right.  I'll include that in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it matter which gets used as the column and which gets used as
> the row?

Yes, it does. I'm imagining some questions your system would have to answer, for instance: `what is the lowest median income in the country`. If your have "town", "postcode" and "median income" as columns, this is a very easy query:

```
select min(median_income)
from my_table
```

If you have columns "metricname" , "SydneySY1", "SydneySY2"..., that query becomes much more complicated (the query below probably won't work on most databases) :

```
select least(SydneySY1, SydneySY2....)
from my_table
where metricname = 'median_income'
```

This is a trivial example, but it gets very complicated very quickly - which localities have the highest median income and a population over 100.000? Which localities are in the top 5% for population but the lowest for median income?

Of course, your output report might want the data structured as rows of localities and (some of) the metrics; in this case, you can use a pivot function  (many database engines support this).

Comment: Thanks Neville, that's really useful, in terms of how the design would best work.  Thanks for that.